# how to count smaller elements on right side of an array using TreeMap in java?

Tags: java, collections, tree

I tried to implement this, but it shows nullPointerException:
What it basically does is it find the first element that is lower than A[i] using lowerKey() method, then find the distance between the above-found element and the beginning of the map.

```
 public static void main(String...aks){
    Integer arr[] = {12, 1, 2, 3, 0, 11, 4 };

   TreeMap<Integer, Integer> treeMap=new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
   int[] count=new int[arr.length];
   for (int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
       treeMap.put(arr[i], 1);
   }

    for (int j=arr.length-1;j>=0;j--) {
        int lowerKey = treeMap.lowerKey(arr[j]);
        count[j] = treeMap.headMap(lowerKey).size();
    }
    for(int elem: count) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that this solution is `O(n^2)`? Method `size()` is `O(n)` for map views returned by all `headMap(...)`, `tailMap(...)` and `subMap(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for `lowerKey`:

> Returns the greatest key strictly less than the given key, or null if
>   there is no such key.

Meaning that it will return `null` for the minimum of the array and therefore fail while calling `headMap` because, from the doc of `headMap`:

> NullPointerException - if toKey is null and this map uses natural
>   ordering, or its comparator does not permit null keys